# Need Sed Command to print between two patterns without repetition

Tags: unix, sed

I have a pattern like the one below

```
Start
Hi
How
Are
You
End
Hi
Start
Hi
How
do
You
Do
End
```

I need the string between the first `Start` and `End`.

I don't want the strings between second `Start` and `End`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it with an `ed` script:

```
<<< '/Start/+1,/End/-1p' | ed -s infile
```

Output:

```
Hi
How
Are
You
```

Comment: Hi Thor, Thanks for your help. But i cant execute the above command. Am i missing something here. I am new to Linux, Please.

Comment: What error do you get? What shell are you using? Make sure `ed` is installed. Try replacing `<<<` with `echo`.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work for me:

`sed -n '/Start/{:a;n;/End/q;p;ba}'`

```
$ echo 'Start
Hi
How
Are
You
End
Hi
Start
Hi
How
do
You
Do
End' | sed -n '/Start/{:a;n;/End/q;p;ba}'
Hi
How
Are
You
```

Comment: Hi Lev, Thanks for the reply.  If if give the exact above echo scenario this works. But if i have a file that has the text it is getting me the second Start to End string. Is there a way to make it first.

Comment: @user1597671 I don't quite get the problem. If you put the same text in a file, it doesn't work? Can you show the command you use? It works for me with `sed -n '/Start/{:a;n;/End/q;p;ba}' filename.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line. For anything else use awk:

```
$ awk '/End/{exit} found{print} /Start/{found=1}' file
Hi
How
Are
You
```

When the current line contains Start set the "found" flag. On the next line and every subsequent line the found flag is set so print that line. When a line containing "End" is seen, exit. All very simple and if necessary in future you can easily control whether Start, End, or both are printed just by moving the {} parts around:

```
$ awk '/End/{exit} /Start/{found=1} found{print}' file 
Start
Hi
How
Are
You
$ awk 'found{print} /End/{exit} /Start/{found=1}' file             
Hi
How
Are
You
End
$ awk '/Start/{found=1} found{print} /End/{exit}' file
Start
Hi
How
Are
You
End
```

or just set the found flag back to zero instead of exiting if you want all the segments between Start/End:

```
$ awk '/End/{found=0} found; /Start/{found=1}' file   
Hi
How
Are
You
Hi
How
do
You
Do
```

If End can occur before Start as suggested in a comment, then just tweak the script to only test for End within the "found" block:

```
awk 'found{ if (/End/) exit; print } /Start/{ found=1 }' file
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach will fail if the word `End` occurs before the word `Start`. I'd use `sed` for this, like Lev Levitsky describes.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Been using sed for 30 years and I still couldn't begin to tell you what the characters :,a,n,;,q,p, and b are doing in that sequence in the sed script or what I'd need to do to modify it if my requirements changed slightly to also print Start and/or End or to test some additional criteria. Hence, I'd use awk.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/Start/,${//!p;/End/q}' file
```